# Raspberry PI freezes

Tags: power-supply

I am running my Pi with an Iphone charger( 5V ~1A). It was running quite well and no hangups or anything. I was mostly using ssh to use it.

Recently, I hooked up and ADC(MCP3202) to connect a sensor to the pi. I ran into a few hangups during the last few days. Are there any ways to determine the root cause of the problem?

The voltage of the PI is usually around 4.75-80.

Comment: Does it show the same behavior when you remove the external hardware?

Comment: @jippe, I went ahead a hooked it to my TV and added a keyboard. It hangs after some time. The voltage is around 4.74-75. I think I need to get a good powersupply for the pi.

Comment: I actually get < 4.75 with a 1A charger and still only ~4.8 with a 3.8A (or various 2A ones), but that little bit does seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

4.75 is the lowest limit for Pi, you definitely have to invest an outrageous amount of about $5 into the decent (5V **sharp**, 2A+) power supply.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected the culprit was the power supply. I changed to a 12W one and no issues :D